# Return an async function from a function in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await

Part 1: What should be the signature of a function returning an async function?

```rust
pub async fn some_async_func(arg: &str) {}

// What should be sig here?
pub fn higher_order_func(action: &str) -> ???
{
    some_async_func
}
```

Part 2: What should be the sig, if based on the action parameter, higher_order_func had to return either async_func1 or async_func2.

I am also interested in learning the performance tradeoffs if there are multiple solutions. Please note that I'd like to return the function itself as an fn pointer or an Fn* trait, and not the result of invoking it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Returning a function

Returning the actual function pointer requires heap allocation and a wrapper:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

pub async fn some_async_func(arg: &str) {}

pub fn some_async_func_wrapper<'a>(arg: &'a str)
    -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + 'a>>
{
    Box::pin(some_async_func(arg))
}

pub fn higher_order_func<'a>(action: &str)
    -> fn(&'a str) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + 'a>>
{
    some_async_func_wrapper
}
```

Why boxing? `higher_order_func` needs to have a concrete return type, which is a function pointer. The pointed function needs to also have a concrete return type, which is impossible for `async` function since it returns opaque type. In theory, it could be possible to write return type as `fn(&'a str) -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a`, but this would require much more guesswork from the compiler and currently is not supported.

If you are OK with `Fn` instead of `fn`, you can get rid of the wrapper:

```
pub async fn some_async_func(arg: &str) {}

pub fn higher_order_func<'a>(action: &str)
    -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + 'a>>
{
    |arg: &'a str| {
        Box::pin(some_async_func(arg))
    }
}
```

To return a different function based on `action` value, you will need to box the closure itself, which is one more heap allocation:

```rust
pub async fn some_async_func_one(arg: &str) {}
pub async fn some_async_func_two(arg: &str) {}

pub fn higher_order_func<'a>(action: &str)
    -> Box<dyn Fn(&'a str) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + 'a>>>
{
    if action.starts_with("one") {
        Box::new(|arg: &'a str| {
            Box::pin(some_async_func_one(arg))
        })
    } else {
        Box::new(|arg: &'a str| {
            Box::pin(some_async_func_two(arg))
        })
    }
}
```

### Alternative: returning a future

To simplify things, consider returning a future itself instead of a function pointer. This is virtually the same, but much nicer and does not require heap allocation:

```rust
pub async fn some_async_func(arg: &str) {}

pub fn higher_order_func_future<'a>(action: &str, arg: &'a str)
    -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a
{
    some_async_func(arg)
}
```

It might look like, when `higher_order_func_future` is called, `some_async_func` is getting executed - but this is **not** the case. Because of the way async functions work, when you call `some_async_func`, **no user code is getting executed**. The function call returns a `Future`: the actual function body will be executed **only** when someone awaits the returned future.

You can use the new function almost the same way as the previous function:

```rust
// With higher order function returning function pointer
async fn my_function() {
    let action = "one";
    let arg = "hello";
    higher_order_func(action)(arg).await;
}

// With higher order function returning future
async fn my_function() {
    let action = "one";
    let arg = "hello";
    higher_order_func_future(action, arg).await;
}
```

Notice, once more, that in both cases the actual `some_async_func` body is executed **only** when the future is awaited.

If you wanted to be able to call different async functions based on `action` value, you need boxing again:

```rust
pub async fn some_async_func_one(arg: &str) {}
pub async fn some_async_func_two(arg: &str) {}

pub fn higher_order_func_future<'a>(action: &str, arg: &'a str)
    -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()> + 'a>>
{
    if action.starts_with("one") {
        Box::pin(some_async_func_one(arg))
    } else {
        Box::pin(some_async_func_two(arg))
    }
}
```

Still, this is just one heap allocation, so I strongly advise returning a future. The only scenario that I can imagine where the previous solution is better is when you want to save the boxed closure somewhere and use it many times. In this case, excessive allocation happens only once, and you spare some CPU time by dispatching the call based on `action` only once - when you make the closure.

Comment: The answer invokes the function and returns the result, rather than return the function itself. I'd like to return a function pointer (function item would work too).

Comment: Edited the answer. Most likely, you don't really need the function pointer; if you are sure that you do, please share your use case details.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I was trying to port over some patterns from another language, which involved sending pointers back. I could modify them to use Future, but I also wanted to learn how it could be done. Your post was very informative and of great help on both counts.

Comment: You run into wanting to return the async function when it's the time of the call that matters, or when the calling the higher order function creates some local state: eg. when the higher order function is caching the result of an async function for some period (determined by the result of the function, so you can't just do the standard select with a timeout).

Comment: Is this still the best way to do it in stable rust(2021)?

Comment: This is the top 5% good answer I've seen so fay.  Thanks for the answer.  ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, what you'd want is a nested impl trait: `-> impl Fn(&str) -> impl Future<Output = ()>`. But nested impl trait is not supported. However, you can emulate that using a trait.

The idea is to define a trait that will abstract over the notion of "function returning a future". If our function would take a `u32`, for example, it could look like:

```
trait AsyncFn: Fn(u32) -> Self::Future {
    type Future: Future<Output = ()>;
}
impl<F, Fut> AsyncFn for F
where
    F: Fn(u32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    type Future = Fut;
}
```

And then we would take `impl AsyncFn`. Trying to apply that naively to `&str` [doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c3b44485a7e09e29a956a93a602fc23):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:16:27
   |
16 | fn higher_order_func() -> impl AsyncFn {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&str) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {some_async_func} as FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&str) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {some_async_func} as FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output`
```

The error may look very strange, but it arises from the fact that `async fn` returns a future bound by the lifetime of all of its argument, i.e. for a signature `async fn foo<'a>(arg: &'a str)`, the future is not `impl Future<Output = ()>` but `impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a`. There is a way to capture this relationship in our trait, we just need to make it generic over the argument and use [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

```rust
trait AsyncFn<Arg>: Fn(Arg) -> Self::Future {
    type Future: Future<Output = ()>;
}
impl<Arg, F, Fut> AsyncFn<Arg> for F
where
    F: Fn(Arg) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    type Future = Fut;
}
```

And then we specify the type as:

```rust
fn higher_order_func() -> impl for<'a> AsyncFn<&'a str> {
    some_async_func
}
```

Comment: Worked great! (for my use-case anyway) I put together a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Venryx/f4602fc1fbbd353b7839ed87b0f4e147), with some extensions of the `AsyncFn` trait for use with output-types and variable numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great accepted answer, depending on your use case it's also possible to "fake" the higher order function and avoid any heap allocations by using a simple macro to expand the wrapper code in-place instead:

```rs
pub async fn some_async_func(arg: &str) {}

macro_rules! higher_order_func {
    ($action: expr) => {
        some_async_func
    };
}

fn main() {
    let future = higher_order_func!("action")("arg");
}
```