# Returning a future-generating closure from a function

Tags: rust, async-await, future

When checking the following code:

```rs
pub fn producer<F>() -> impl Fn() -> F
where
    F: std::future::Future<Output = ()>,
{
    || async move {
        println!("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I get following compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:5:8
   |
1  |   pub fn producer<F>() -> impl Fn() -> F
   |                   - this type parameter
...
5  |       || async move {
   |  ________^
6  | |         println!("Hello, World!");
7  | |     }
   | |_____^ expected type parameter `F`, found opaque type
   | 
  ::: /Users/tf/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:61:43
   |
61 |   pub const fn from_generator<T>(gen: T) -> impl Future<Output = T::Return>
   |                                             ------------------------------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `F`
                 found opaque type `impl Future`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

However, the future should eventually resolve to unit. I have seen multiple error messages, basically all related to type mismatches, while I am suspecting something a like a missing `Sized` marker. But then again boxing the closure didn't help either.

The usual questions:

1. What keeps the compiler from accepting my closure as the proper type?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: This kind of pattern unfortunately doesn't work without using a trait object: e.g. `Pin<Box<dyn Future<...>>>`. I'll adapt the wording from [kreo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168459/2189130): *"In theory, it could be possible to write return type as `impl Fn() -> impl Future<Output=()>`, but this ... currently is not supported."*

Comment: There's a conceptual disconnect here that might help being made explicit. The type parameter (`F`) is something the caller decides and can even explicitly specify. It comes from the "outside". However, you want it to be a particular type (that the compiler makes out of that `async move` block). So, from the "inside".

Comment: @JeffGarrett Precisely that - if one could emulate `impl Trait` in return position with a generic, the `impl Trait` syntax would likely never have been added. The confusion might come from `impl Trait` in argument position, where it is indeed mostly equivalent to an anonymous generic with the specified trait bound.