# How to create a generic function to wrap an async closure?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, closures, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a generic function that has the impressive goal of wrapping an async closure. So for all intents and purposes, it would treat the closure as a *black box* and simply run some setup logic before and some logic after, depending on the return value of the closure that is passed in.

Here is an MRE example code I have put together so far. I was also testing it out in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b44254dced7820438fe8343a1a39329a) as well.

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyEvent {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyContext {
    pub fn_name: String,
}

pub struct HelpAnError {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_age: u8 = 29;

    let doing_work_hard = move |event: MyEvent, ctx: MyContext| async move {
        println!("I'm working hard, i promise!");
        println!("Ma i'm already {} yrs old!", my_age);
        Ok::<_, HelpAnError>(())
    };

    let doing_chores_hard = lets_wrap_da_closure(doing_work_hard);

    // does all the chores that Ma assigned to me
    let _ = doing_chores_hard(Default::default(), Default::default()).await;
}

fn lets_wrap_da_closure<
    C: Fn(MyEvent, MyContext) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = Result<(), HelpAnError>>,
>(
    do_work_hard: C,
) -> fn(MyEvent, MyContext) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), HelpAnError>>>> {
    move |event: MyEvent, ctx: MyContext| {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("I'm doin my chores Ma, I promise!");
            // **help** - if I uncomment this it fails!
            // do_work_hard(event, ctx).await;
            println!("Yay! The chores are now complit.");
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help or pointers on how to get this to work with the rust compiler, which doesn't seem too friendly to me here. I feel as I've struggled for hours but am not smart enough or skilled with rust enough to know how to satisfy the compiler rules.

I also checked out [Return an async function from a function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167939/return-an-async-function-from-a-function-in-rust) and have got the tip to use `Box::pin` accordingly. However I'm having trouble implementing it for my specific use case, i.e. where I want to create a generic function to wrap a callable that returns a `Future` in particular. Thanks and let me know if I need to clarify on anything.

---

**Update**: Thanks to help from @Jakub. Here is my revised (working) code below:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyEvent {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyContext {
    pub fn_name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct HelpAnError {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_age: u8 = 29;

    let doing_work_hard = move |event: MyEvent, ctx: MyContext| async move {
        println!("I'm working hard, i promise!");
        println!("Ma i'm already {} yrs old!", my_age);
        Ok::<_, HelpAnError>(())
    };

    let doing_chores_hard = lets_wrap_da_closure(doing_work_hard);

    // does all the chores that Ma assigned to me
    let _ = doing_chores_hard(Default::default(), Default::default()).await;
}

fn lets_wrap_da_closure<
    'a,
    C: Fn(A1, A2) -> F,
    A1,
    A2,
    E: std::fmt::Debug,
    F: Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + 'a,
>(
    do_work_hard: C,
) -> impl Fn(A1, A2) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + 'a>> {
    move |event: A1, ctx: A2| {
        let fut = do_work_hard(event, ctx);
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("I'm doin my chores Ma, I promise!");
            // it WORKS! wow, amazing ~
            match fut.await {
                Ok(_) => println!("All systems are a GO!"),
                Err(e) => println!("I ran into issue doing my chores: {:?}", e),
            };
            println!("Yay! The chores are now complit.");
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

*Side note*: it would've been nice to wrap the `dyn Future<Output = Result<(), HelpAnError>>` into a generic or perhaps just reuse the `F`, but at this point I'm just glad that was able to get it working :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyEvent {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyContext {
    pub fn_name: String,
}

pub struct HelpAnError {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_age: u8 = 29;

    let doing_work_hard = move |event: MyEvent, ctx: MyContext| async move {
        println!("I'm working hard, i promise!");
        println!("Ma i'm already {} yrs old!", my_age);
        Ok::<_, HelpAnError>(())
    };

    let doing_chores_hard = lets_wrap_da_closure(doing_work_hard);

    // does all the chores that Ma assigned to me
    let _ = doing_chores_hard(Default::default(), Default::default()).await;
}

fn lets_wrap_da_closure<
    C: Fn(MyEvent, MyContext) -> F + 'static,
    F: Future<Output = Result<(), HelpAnError>> + 'static,
>(
    do_work_hard: C,
) -> impl Fn(MyEvent, MyContext) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), HelpAnError>>>> {
    move |event: MyEvent, ctx: MyContext| {
        // this is the only way i can satisfy the compiler, do not worry,
        // future will get executed only upon await and this call is just 
        // creating the future we are passing
        let fut = do_work_hard(event, ctx);
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("I'm doin my chores Ma, I promise!");
            // **help** - if I uncomment this it fails!
            drop(fut.await);
            println!("Yay! The chores are now complit.");
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: *Amazing*! I'll have to read up more on this specific use case, assuming that it's mentioned in the Rust book or elsewhere, but at this point I'm just really glad that what I proposed was actually achievable in some manner. Props to you my friend!

Comment: Just a minor note, but what I found is that instead of the explicit `drop` syntax, you can also have it like `let _ = fut.await` and ignore the explicit `Result`. I think the only reason you can't use the `?` shorthand here is because I haven't correctly implemented Error for my `HelpAnError` type. I'm not entirely sure about the difference between `drop` and this approach, but if I understand correctly it should have more or less the same result.

Comment: It's just my preference, it mainly proves useful when you want to make a shorthand branch of match statement but not return any value from the branch.